# Jquery searching for an active class then add a class to a specific a tag

Tags: jquery

I am quite new in Jquery. I have this html code please help me.

```
<body>
<header class="wrapper"> 
        <ul class="language-switcher">
            <li class="en first active">
                <a href="/web/en" class="language-link active" lang="en">English</a>
            </li>
            <li class="fr">
                <a href="/web/fr" class="language-link" lang="fr">French</a>
            </li>    
        </ul>    
    </header>
    <section class="region">       
        <ul class="menu">
            <li class="menu__item is-leaf first leaf">
                 <a href="/web/en/service" class="menu__link active">Service</a>
            </li>
        </ul>    
  </section>
</body>
```

So the question is how to write a Jquery to search for the class active in a tag in here

```
<li class="menu__item is-leaf first leaf">
    <a href="/web/en/service" class=" active">Service</a>
</li>
```

if the link is active then add `.untranslated` to this

```
<li class="fr">
    <a href="/web/fr" class="language-link" lang="fr">French</a>
</li>
```

** Come on people. If you cannot help please do not mark this down,  as there are people like me out there looking for an answer. Thank you for your help

Comment: Start with reading something about selectors. Or provide some code you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

At the most basic you could do this -

```
$('.active').closest('li').addClass('untranslated');
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd be best to read up on css selectors. These are easily found with google

if you want to select an element with two classes you just concatenate them, i.e.

```
var someElement = $('.menu__link.active');
```

You'll need to be a bit clearer about adding the translate class problem. 
I can't see any connection between the elements and you haven't mentioned any events or actions to connect them so its hard to suggest an approach

EDIT:

If you then want to switch the class on the link for french, you could have a toggle on what ever event you are using to trigger the change. I'd put something on the element to make your life easier such as a id or french

```
<li id="french" class="fr">
    <a href="/web/fr" class="language-link" lang="fr">French</a>
</li>


$('#french a').toggleClass('untranslated');
```

Comment: I removed the .menu_link, so there is only .active. So basically, my website has 2 languages, English and French. In the English home page, there is an Service link and it is marked as "active". So if the link is active, I want to add .untranslated to language switcher for french.